# Anomalous acceleration noted when using C++2011 threads instead of OpenMP in matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, boost-thread

Writing a demonstration code (matrix multiplication) for my students in order to show that one MUST use the cache correctly even when using parallel code, I have found that using C++2011 threads ( via `boost::thread`  ) outperforms OpenMP (parallel for) threads by more then a factor 2 !

The only possible explanation I can imagine is that in C++2011 each thread always runs on the  same core. So there is the possibility to keep data on cache.

Could this be  real ?

The demo code is quite long (and boring same matrix init and multiply repeated four times in the correct, wrong ( bad cache access ), scalar and OpenMP ) and can be found at :

http://www.giuseppelevi.com/uploads/3/2/9/8/3298932/matrix_mul_boost_thread.cpp

The compiler I'm using is VS2010. BOOST 1.45 Processor : Intel Core I5 M430.
`omp_get_wtime()` was used to profile each part of it.
In order to give some numbers in a run I obtained this figures:

Scalar execution time: 14.42 sec

BOOST Thread: 2.28

OpenMP Thread: 5.10

Because there are only 2 physical cores with hyperthreading the 6.31 speedup ( vs scalar ) obtained by BOOST Thread is quite surprising and "anomalous".

Comment: I'm going to downvote just because there isn't much relevant information here. Post code, profiling information, etc.

Comment: Ok. Here we go: Profiling info is obtained directly via omp_get_wtime() function. Code is here:http://www.giuseppelevi.com/uploads/3/2/9/8/3298932/matrix_mul_boost_thread.cpp

Comment: Sorry for the italian comments in the code BUT the course is in Italian. Note also the commented out parallel matrix transposition..... that is done for showing that using parallelism is not allways convenient

Comment: Could you edit that into the main post? Also, I suggest you try using an actual profiling as that can show more statistics. Thanks.

Comment: done as you wish.... could you please try to answer the question and clear the downnote ?... I will try to make some more detailed profiling in the mean time. BTW the processor is an Itel Core I5 M430. Will also add this info in the main question.

Comment: How does boost::thread version runs VS omp version with 1 thread only?  Try changing omp scedule to dynamic/static with various chunking.

Comment: Comparing two different implementations, both using threads, does not show superlinear acceleration. Superlinear acceleration means that when we double the number of threads/cores used (but the program is otherwise the same) we get more than double the performance. I don't think this is ever seen. Approaching a linear improvement is the ideal that designers strive for. Even if the threads have completely independent work which is integrated into the final result at a very low cost, how can it be superlinear.

Comment: I believe that it is true that each Windows thread is pegged to a particular core. When a core has a context switch, this does not force a dump and reload of the L3 cache. L3 is reloaded as needed. So if a core has a quick switch out of context and then back again, the L3 cache stays mostly intact.

Comment: A useful sanity check is to covert your times into a flop rate and compare it to the peak of your device, and the performance of an optimized BLAS on the same problem. That will immediately show whether something is clearly wrong, or one case is either very efficient or very inefficient. The explanation is probably a combination of all of the above.

Comment: Something is very strange here... I would be very surprised if you even got 3x speedup with hyperthreading, but 6x with 2 cores + HT is just impossible. Either your serial version is somehow unnaturally slow, or the parallel version does not work correctly. Have you tried to verify at the end if the parallel implementations return correct results?

Comment: @Kaz, I think you should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Hi, I have verified that the results are correct. All the versions of the matrix multiplication give the same result. I know that numbers seems unnatural .... thats why I'm asking here.  I have found an important information about thread handling in windows 7 from :http://itexpertvoice.com/home/multi-core-support-in-windows-7/

Comment: From that page: "So with Windows 7, there is a concerted effort to assign cores to an execution pipeline, such as a core. Now, threads get sent back to the same core where the last threads for that application executed, so an application more closely sticks with one core. This lets idle cores shut down and makes for smarter processor affinity. Instead of throwing threads at every core, it just goes to one."  I will now verify about BOOST thread affinity. Can anyone make an experiment and try the code in windows 7 or any other OS?

Comment: @Tudor Thaks a lot. Probably I have found the problem BUT thats opens another question. I have revritten the scalar part just encapsulating it in a Lambda functor and thats acceleratats it a lot. Doing the same even for the OpenMP part accelerats it also..... making figures that make much more sense:

SCALAR 5.52

BOOST THREAD 2.14

OMP 2.15

So the problem was in the comparison of a lambda functor and a normal cicle.... May I now ask why the Lambda Functor are so optimized ? Modified code can be found at:[link](http://www.giuseppelevi.com/uploads/3/2/9/8/3298932/matrix_mul_boost_l_thread.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

By default, schedule(static,1) will be used, which often results in false sharing, and can result in sometimes suboptimal scheduling.
Try schedule(guided) instead, this often results in much better scaling.